# How to group by an attribute and order by date

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

**Medics**

```
CREATE TABLE "medic" (
   "id" BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   "name" CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ("id")
```

);

**Comments**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "comment" (
   "id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
   "medic_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
   "comment" CHARACTER VARYING(1024) NOT NULL,
   "created_at" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
   CONSTRAINT pk_comment PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_comment_medic FOREIGN KEY (medic_id)
   REFERENCES medic(id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Now I want to get `medic_id, name, comments_count` and all `ordered by created_at`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, COUNT(c.id)
FROM COMMENT AS c
JOIN medic AS m ON m.id = c.medic_id
GROUP BY m.id, m.name, c.created_at
ORDER BY c.created_at DESC
```

But obviously this can't work because it makes no sense to group by date although I have to do it when I want to order by date.

Another appraoch was to work with window functions. Particularly `rank() over (partition by m.id order by c.created_at desc)`. But in this case I lose the ordering over all records.

Here's some [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9aef5/1).

I am using Postgres 9.3

Comment: The question would be clearer with an exemplary desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to order by *the most recent* comment date:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, COUNT(c.id)
FROM COMMENT c JOIN
     medic m
     ON m.id = c.medic_id
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
ORDER BY MAX(c.created_at) DESC;
```